# How do I 'embed' a manifest in an assembly using VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, assemblies, embed

Using VS2005, how do I 'embed' a manifest in an assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link that will help you to 'embed' a manifest in an assembly in VS2005

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120205818/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/cheller/archive/2006/08/24/718757.aspx)